# Horizontal tree/org chart/uml using QUERY or just CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, tree, uml

Wondering if anyone out there has any pointers to a jquery plugin or any other project which would allow one to create a horizontal tree / org chart like the example here:

http://www.yworks.com/products/yfilessilverlight/Demo.yFiles.Graph.Collapse.html

or

https://google-visualization-api-issues.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=470030000&name=tech_tree3.jpg&token=r1J_Ga0ZN1bupa8yNB_SLFTFMcI%3A1364399622331&inline=1

Something not using flash or silveright though... javascript/jquery/css ideal, especially with a collapsible function!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JIT's (http://philogb.github.com/jit/demos.html)
Space Tree

http://philogb.github.com/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

one more example

http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-horizontal-tree/4294567?sso?WT.ac=category_item&WT.seg_1=category_item&WT.z_author=jscode